# A single connection to multiple Postgresql data schemas. Some read-only

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a postgresql database that has multiple schemas. Only one of them has entities that perform CRUD operations against the system. The rest of the schemas must be used as read only.

I have read a lot of Symfony and Doctrine documentation. I know that it is possible to define entities as read-only and define the database schema that maps an entity.

Of the read-only schemas, I only need to query a small subset of tables.

My doubts are related to the synchronization that Symfony does with the Database.

Is it possible to declare as entities only the tables that the application requires for read-only? Or should I declare each of the entities of each of the schemas that I use read-only? I ask this because when I run the *make: migration* command by console, since it does not declare all of it, the migration script makes a drop of each of the tables that are not defined in my application. Obviously, I can modify the migration script and remove those lines but I am concerned that future updates will inadvertently delete these tables. For me it would be a big problem.

As an alternative I have read that you could use these read-only schemas by making use of Doctrine's DBAL. Not the ORM. However, I am not clear if it is possible under a single connection with multiple schemas, those that are read-only to use DBAL and the schema that interacts with the application use the ORM in a standard way so that when you execute a *make_migration* or similar commands only sync or consider the read / write scheme.

I know that I could solve the problem by generating the schema in a new database. Define two connections. One for read-only schemas. The other one with which it performs CRUD operations and set it as the default connection. Synchronization operations synchronize on the default schema with which the problem could be solved. This would be my plan "B".

In short, I would like to solve the problem with a single connection to a Postgresql database with multiple schemas. All of them read-only except one. Preferably only declare the entities that the application makes of the schema data read-only. These read-only schemas have about 100 tables each. The application only uses 5 tables.

I apologize for my English. I have used google translation services. I hope it is clearly understood.

Comment: You can instruct doctrine to [ignore some tables](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#manual-tables) when generating the migrations.

Comment: Thanks @msg for commenting. I have tried what you indicate but without success. I put a little more detail of my real problem.

I have a "_personal_" schema with 76 tables.

I am developing a solution that works on the same database under a schema named _"califi"_. Contains 9 tables.

The application operates on all the tables in the "califi" schema (read and write) and queries some data from a few tables in "personal" (read only).

It seems to me that the _schema_filter_ option is not possible. Or at least I haven't come up with a regular expression that satisfies what I've explained.

Comment: Let's say the `personal` schema contains `table1` through `table9` and you are interested only on `2` and `5`. The following regex shouldn't affect anything in the `califi` schema and other tables in the `personal` schema: `^personal\.(?!table2|table5).*$`. It might get a little impractical if your entities grow, but it's easier to foolproof it than to edit _every_ migration.